# How to loop through an excel sheet from word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am struggling to find out how i can loop through all rows in excel from word. What I want to achieve is that if there is something in the WP column in excel then save the active worddocument with that filename. However i cant figure out something simple as getting the last row(might be empty rows in between), i just get error code 424, which according to MSDN does not give me any real hint whats wrong. Any ideas whats wrong?

```
Public Sub test()
Dim xlapp As Object
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

myFileName = "Z:\Dokumentstyring\UnderArbeid\PARTSLIST.xlsm"
xlapp.Workbooks.Open myFileName
xlapp.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xlapp.Visible = False

a = xlapp.sheets("List").Range("A1").Value
b = firstBlankRow(xlapp)
c = getColumn("WP", xlapp)

xlapp.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
xlapp.Quit
Set xlapp = Nothing
End Sub
```

My function to receive the last row:

```
 Function firstBlankRow(ByRef xlapp) As Long
 'returns the row # of the row after the last used row
 'Or the first row with no data in it

With xlapp.sheets("List")
    '~~> Check if there is any data in the sheet
    'If xlapp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        firstBlankRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
    'Else
        firstBlankRow = 1
    'End If

End With
End Function
```

Here is my function for getting the column number

```
Public Function getColumn(header As String, ByRef xlapp) As Integer
    Dim rng1 As Range
    With xlapp.sheets("List")
        Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, Columns.Count)).Find(header, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            getColumn = rng1.Column
        Else
            MsgBox "Column " & header & " does not exist, Typo??", vbCritical
            getColumn = -1
        End If

    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Debug your code step by step using F8. That will tell you what line is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks @JLILI, with that code i get error 1004. Oh sorry that i forgot to mention which line that failed in the original post. It can't find the value of xlup if I set it to 1 it goes through but return wrong number. Then it fails here: `getColumn = rng1.Column`

Comment: Can you please add `debug.print(rng1.Address(External:=False))` after `Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, Columns.Count)).Find(header, , xlValues, xlWhole)` and tell what does it print?

Comment: `Debug.Print (rng1.Address)` says method can not be found. It seems that the problem is that i am trying to access it from word might be the issue? The code works in excel, but not from word for some reason.

Comment: There is a problem with `rng`. The range you're defining `dim rng as range` is not an Excel range. It's a word range. I think that's the issue.

Comment: Good point! `Dim rng1 As Excel.Range` is not the correct syntax. Any idea how to set the type? And I thought it should be easy to change my code from excel to word...

Comment: `Dim rng1 As object` and then set it like this `Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, Columns.Count)).Find(header, , xlValues, xlWhole)`

Comment: Basically just change `Dim rng1 As range` to `Dim rng1 As object`

Comment: That works! however i needed to comment out the find method. I guess i need to look up all the constant values defined by excel (xlup,xlValues,xlWhole) and then set it directly to get it to work as desired. I am getting there:)

Comment: Seems the problem is late binding  as seen [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?47227-Word-and-excel-Late-binding) . Well i guess i will just use excel to figure out the values and then the rest should be ok.

Comment: hold on i got it for you

Comment: Check my answer, if it helps you, please tick the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our conversation in the comments, change `Dim Rng1 As Range` to
`Dim Rng1 As Object`.

You can find the actual values of [XlDirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff820880.aspx), [Xlvalues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff822180.aspx), [xlwhole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff823160.aspx) enums.

Preferably, it's better to do it like this:

```
Private Const xlUp as long = -4162 
'and so on
```

**Edit1:**

Here's an adjusted function that solves your problem (I've tested it on my machine)

```
Public Function getColumn(header As String, ByRef xlapp) As Long
        Dim rng1 As Object
        With xlapp.sheets("List") 
            Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count))
            If rng1 Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("ERROR: Range object is empty.")
            getColumn = -1
            Exit Function
            End If
            For Each m In rng1
            If m = "WP" Then
            getColumn = m.Column
            Exit Function
            End If
            Next m
            MsgBox "Column " & header & " does not exist, Typo??", vbCritical
            getColumn = -1
       End With
    End Function
```

Comment: `Private Const xlUp = -4162
Private Const xlWhole = 1
Private Const xlValue = -4163` Seems to be the values as u said aboved, however the rng.find method can not be found from word. What i try to achieve is to get the column number where the text "WP" can be found. `c = getColumn("WP", xlapp)` because people tends to add or remove columns from the worksheet and hence a static column number does unfortunately not work for me. I will post the final code and tick it of as answered as soon as I get it to work.

Comment: @skatun, please check my answer i hope that helps you fellow engineer ;)